# How do I tell my boss I am moving to a different organization?

Tags: professionalism, management, new-job, job-change, job-offer

I always wanted to do a kind of job I found a year back. But due to organizational changes, the entire team moved to a different project and I don't find the current work challenging and hence it is demotivating me and am losing my self confidence.

I started applying recently and found a new job which is not the same as I "always" wanted to do.

How do I tell my boss I got a new job? Will it be perceived as I changed because I was not capable of doing something?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell my boss I got a new job?

This can depend on your firm policy and culture of the firm. Your firm may require his approval to finalize the move. You need him to know you're unhappy with where you are and what you're doing, but I would get as hard a guarantee that the new job is yours as you can before you inform your boss that you intend to make the change. It also may not be official policy, but your current boss may have the influence to stop your move.

When it's time to tell him, you see him face-to-face (if possible) and you tell him as soon as possible, but when the move is as finalized as can be, and not before. If you tell him before the move is as finalized as you can make it, you may wind up replaced without a place to land.

If he's willing to let you go, or he has no say in the matter, he may be a little disappointed, but he'll take it like a champ.

You'll also want to make yourself as available as your new duties will allow to consult with your replacement if you want to ensure your move does not leave you with a bad reputation.

> Will it be perceived as I changed because I was not capable of doing something?

You already have the new job. If the question ever comes up in the future, you tell them what you've told us.

> The entire team moved to a different project and I d[id]n't find the
>   current work challenging.

It wasn't what you were originally hired to do, so you moved. No one will consider you poorly for it.

Comment: Strong suggestion: Even (especially!) if the move is within a company, it's a good idea to do the two-weeks-notice thing, or longer, to make sure that most of your knowledge about the thing you've been working on is transferred to someone who's staying. You can also promise to be available to consult/advise whoever will be taking over your role, subject of course to the needs of your new assignment. Ideally, of course, you should have spoken with your boss about this before you started looking so he/she could start arranging to bring in other manpower to replace you.

Comment: @keshlam I added the points you brought up, except I can't agree with your final point. If you're replaced before you've arranged and finalized your move, you increase your risk of not being able to find work. You are in a much better negotiating position when you are currently employed.

Comment: @AarronHall: That issue doesn't apply to a move within the company, which is the case being discussed.

Comment: @keshlam I'd argue against it all else equal, but it's certainly a more delicate matter as an in-firm transfer. Some firms require the prior manager's approval to make a move like that, so ASAP would be the best possible option in that case. I'll address your point.